# Azure App Service - WebSocket - Reached the end of the file

Tags: c#, azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service

everything good? I have an application in azure/App Service (WebSocket) that was working normally.

From a week ago I started to have the following error being presented in the log stream when I have to open a websocket connection...

22-10-07T14:49:54  PID[1752] Information Operation=SafetyAccessController.Dispose
2022-10-07T14:49:54  PID[1752] Warning     ***** new Open WebSocket Gate: 34B1F7D5DCC9
2022-10-07T14:49:54  PID[1752] Warning     ***** Error on  WebSocket Gate: 34B1F7D5DCC9  error?:**Reached the end of the file**  state=Aborted    status=

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Haven't modified this program for a few months now and out of nowhere this error started to appear and the client's webSocket connection started to be rejected.

I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem from 29.09.22.
We opened tehnical ticket on Azure, posted all requested data (network and HAR traces) and we are waiting for response.
Our app is on west europe server.

Let you know when they answer..
Please you can post this question on microsoft forum to speed them up!

Comment: Okay I'll do it.

Comment: The answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you @MustafaBazghandi for smart comment!

Answer (score 0):

App service engineering team has identified that this issue happened after recent upgrade.
This happens if the http response 101 Switching Protocol has the Content-Length header
Please check if you can remove the Content-Length response header in your application to mitigate this issue as we have seen successful behavior after removing this header.

This is temporary workaround. Permanent fix will be rolled out soon and it may take 1-2 weeks.